# How to change start date in Kendo Scheduler

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

I have designed a scheduler using Kendo UI. Now my problem is every time, the calendar is loading from 1st of the month but I want it to load from the first day of the week which has schedules.

For example in the below image it should load from 2nd of the month rather than 26th of the previous month.

[image]
I have tried the following,

- In the **dataBound** event I have used jquery to hide the top row.

  $('.k-scheduler-table').find('tr')[0].remove()

But I want 6 rows every time and when the top row is removed I want the next week to be added below. Please suggest me some way to achieve this.

**Note:** I am a newbie to Kendo UI, Sorry if I am wrong some where.

Answer (score 0):

The KendoUI scheduler does not allow the type of view for which you are looking. Currently, the scheduler supports the following [view types](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/scheduler#configuration-views.type): "day", "week", "workWeek", "month", "agenda", "timeline", "timelineWeek", "timelineWorkWeek" and "timelineMonth".

If you want to view the calendar events starting with the first day that has events, I suggest that you check out the "agenda" view type.

In your example, however, you have selected the "month" view. In general, calendar apps show all days of a month in the "month" view, even if that requires the calendar to show days from the previous month. Kendo is trying to mirror that general pattern.

The type of view you are looking for is interesting, but I've never seen it done anywhere, so I unfortunately doubt that Kendo is going to support it.

Answer (score 0):

The Kendo Scheduler has several built-in views but it also allows you to make your own custom views and even extend the built-in ones.

You can see a demo [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/scheduling/scheduler/how-to/custom-views/custom-month-view-with-event-count-in-show-more-button).

Answer (score 0):

In the Razor you can bind view starttime also can be set from jQuery f.e.

```
.Views(views =>
    {
        views.TimelineMonthView(timeline =>
        {
            timeline.StartTime(Model.StartTime);
            timeline.EndTime(Model.EndTime);
            timeline.MajorTick(1440);
            timeline.Selected(true);
            timeline.EventHeight(10);
        });
    })
```